# C++Builder can't compile properly (doesn't recognize some functions)

Tags: c++, c++builder

I downloaded C++Builder from embarcadero.com, for studying purposes, and I am learning from this book (it is in Romanian) - https://en.calameo.com/read/002801569838bdc5a9164.

I'm trying to compile the code from page 35, but the console doesn't recognize some functions written here. Maybe my settings are off, or I don't understand something.

Here is my `Unit1.cpp` (didn't write the whole code yet). The error is:

> [bcc32c Error] Unit1.cpp(54): out-of-line definition of 'FormCreate' does not match any declaration in 'TForm1'

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
AnsiString s="";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double eval(AnsiString exp)
{
    AnsiString op = "", c = "";
    double a;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= exp.Length(); i++)
    {
        if(exp[i] >= '0' && exp[i] <= '9' || exp[i]=='.') c = exp[i];
        else
        {
            if(op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/')
            {
                if(op == '+') a = a + c.ToDouble();
                if(op == '-') a = a - c.ToDouble();
                if(op == '*') a = a * c.ToDouble();
                if(op == '/') a = a / c.ToDouble();
                op = s[i];
            }
            else
            {
                a = c.ToDouble();
                op = exp[i];
            }
            c = "";
        }
    }
    if(op == '+') a = a + c.ToDouble();
    if(op == '-') a = a - c.ToDouble();
    if(op == '*') a = a * c.ToDouble();
    if(op == '/') a = a / c.ToDouble();
    return a;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender) //Here I get an error when calling this function
{
     Calcule->Clear();
     Calcule->SetFocus();
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button12Click(TObject *Sender) //same error when calling is here
{
    Calcule->Clear();
    Calcule->Text = AnsiString(eval(s));
    s = "";
    Calcule->SetFocus();
}
```

and here is the `Unit1.h` code:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Menus.hpp>
#include <Vcl.ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *APASAA;
    TEdit *Calcule;
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    TButton *Button3;
    TButton *Button4;
    TButton *Button5;
    TButton *Button6;
    TButton *Button7;
    TButton *Button8;
    TButton *Button9;
    TButton *Button10;
    TButton *Button11;
    TButton *Button12;
    TButton *Button13;
    TButton *Button14;
    TButton *Button15;
    TButton *Button16;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

The same error appears with the code on page 26.

Comment: Neither `TForm1::FormCreate` nor `TForm1::Button12Click` ar declared anywhere.

Comment: What *are* the error you get? Please [edit] your question to include a copy-paste them (in full and complete, and as *text*).

Comment: If you didn't write the whole code yet, then the errors you are seeing are probably because of that.

Comment: @churill how do I declare functions so the program understands that this function starts working at a certain time: for example, when I press button 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing these declarations in `Unit1.h` under the `__published: // IDE-managed Components` section:

```cpp
void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
void __fastcall Button12Click(TObject *Sender);
```

These are added automatically for you when you assign events via the Object Inspector's `Events` tag. Please note though, that `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events should not be used in C++ *at all*. Ref. to comment by Remy Lebeau below. Instead use the Form's constructor and destructor.

UI components have default events (like buttons have the `OnClick` event) for which prototypes are added automatically when you double click on them in the Form Designer.

Comment: On a side note - you should not be using the `OnCreate` (or `OnDestroy`) event in C++ *at all*.  They are Delphi idioms that can cause illegal behavior in C++.  Use the Form's constructor (and destructor) instead.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the heads up!